# use document.write() to write html in to iframe, but jquery not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have stored a html page in local system, and i try to get the contents then write to an iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="styles/myStlye.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body><button id="buttonClick">Click Me</button></body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buttonClick").click(function(){
            alert("Button clicked.");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

i use document.write() to write the html code to the iframe, but error **SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined** occur when page load in IE9, but work fine in google chrome & firefox.

Comment: sometimes $ occurs problem. use jQuery instead

Comment: Try with jquery cdn.

Comment: Er, `'$' is undefined` happens *when you click the button*? That sounds quite odd, because the handler doesn't have `$` in it, and if `$` wasn't defined, it should have thrown an error on page load.

Comment: tried to use jQuery, and jquery cdn, problem doesn't solve. i changed my question, error occur when page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that IE is executing the JS code before loading in jquery, try loading it in dynamically and listening for onload:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="styles/myStlye.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="buttonClick">Click Me</button>
  <script>
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "js/jquery.min.js";

    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
        $("#buttonClick").click(function () {
          alert("Button clicked.");
        });
      }
    };
    script.onload = function () {
      $("#buttonClick").click(function () {
        alert("Button clicked.");
      });
    };
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your relpy. This method solve the problem, but the code will be longer due to duplicate code.

Comment: You mean both script.onreadystatechange and script.onload are firing?

Comment: yes, 
but not only that, also the code will be longer due to the code in script.onreadystatechange and script.onload is same.

Comment: OK then remove script.onreadystatechange because you only need 1 event to fire. onreadystatechange is only there to support ie8 and before so no need for it if you don't care about that.

Comment: Wow, do `<script>`s not always block in IE9 or something? That's very peculiar!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Thank for Ralph Najm's answer, but I have found another method to solve this problem that I feel is more appropriate.

Wait until the page loaded before execute the script. Below is the example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="styles/myStlye.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body><button id="buttonClick">Click Me</button></body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#buttonClick").click(function(){
                alert("Button clicked.");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```